# output results from a subset of data

Tags: r, subset

Take the simple data as:

```
A <- (1:100)
B <- (4:103)
C <- (100:199)
D <- (1000:1099)

df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)

unique_set <- c('B','C')
```

Now it is simple to create a subset of df accounting for the `unique_set` variables, using

```
df[unique_A]
```

But lets say, i want only a specific row of numbers. Or more specifically for a specific `A` value. If we try this, an error occurs.

```
df[unique_A][df$A == 78]
```

Or

```
df[unique_A & df$A == 78]
```

So what I want it to output is what this returns

```
df[unique_A][78,]
```

While A is in sequential order, the following code work. But I want to know how the user can specific set conditions (ie. the A value) whilst account for our `unique_set` requirement at the same time?
Must one include `A` with the `unique_set` command?

Comment: what is `unique_A`? I'm a bit confused with your question. Probably your are looking `df[df$A == 78, unique_set]`

Comment: yes, sorry that was a typo, but that work fine. So you specific the row, then use `,` to separate, then list the columns. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I will try to explain it more in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `data.frame` subset is looks like:

```
df[condition on rows, condition on columns]
```

So in your case, you want to select all the rows where column A is 78 and at the same time select only columns specified on unique_set:

```
df[df$A == 78, unique_set]
```

Try to play with these examples:

```
df[df$A == 78, c("B", "C")]
df[df$A == 78, c(2, 3)]
df[78, c(1:3)]
```